# Testing ssl HTTPS application locally with Coldfusion

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, coldfusion-10, cfml

I would like to test https related application on my local machine before pushing it to staging and production.
If I try to test on local system, the page just showing (in chrome it gets to the "This webpage has a redirect loop" page).
If any information could be provided that would assist me in setting this up / getting it working and testing, I would be extremely grateful . Thanks

Comment: Please provide what OS and web server you are using.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can have two angles whether this could be related to your specific browser or with your ColdFusion application:

First and foremost can you check it on Firefox or IE just to isolate if this is specific to Chrome. (As I have seen this to come on Chrome more than often)

**if it works on Other Browsers:**

1. probably Chrome is at fault. Go to settings (Options -> Under the Hood -> Content Settings -> Cookies -> Show cookies and other site data)
2. Enter your problem URL in search bar and it would list all related cookies.
3. Select "Remove all"

**if it FAILS on other browsers as well:**

Can you check with perhaps another test application?

Please check with following article by Ben Nadal --
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1666-Ask-Ben-Enforcing-An-SSL-HTTPS-Connection-Based-On-Request.htm

If this persists, please add some more information, on how this has been set up.

Cheers,
Anjaneai

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions you should be able to use a self signed certificate on your local dev box. Once you set this up you should be able to test your site in SSL mode.

Here is one quick tutorial.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx